# Pass a parameter to an event handler or callback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />
```

equivalent to calling .bind:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)} />
```

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

If arrow function does not have its own this, the 1st handleClick() would have a different this as compared to the 2nd one, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
1. <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />

2. <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)} />
```

yes, both function equally if the handle click would not have expected any id as argument, then you could have written it like:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

And this case this will the component whose render is this.
to pass arguments to function, you need to write onClick like this. And first of all, onClick expects a function as the value, not a function call. so to convert handleClick into a function that is bound to correct context(this: Component). you need to write it using bind. bind return you a context bounded function. react the docs at mdn for more understanding.
[bind mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />
```

here `this` nothing but scope of component in which it is rendered.

So,if above button is rendering inside component A,then this point to A component object.

**Note :** here `this` is not `arrow function` property.Its just inheriting the parent scope which nothing but button->render->component A object.

i.e. lexical scope without explicit binding.

```
2. <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)} />
```

only diff you are binding `this` explicitly with `bind` which is again Component A